# Email app allows designation of priority and request for receipt

Tags: email

I am currently using K-9 Mail on my Samsung Vibrant (Galaxy S) and I use squirrel mail on my computer.  When using SquirrelMail I can designate a priority for outgoing emails (low, normal, high) as well as request delivery and read receipts. Is there an app that allows me to set these designations/requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any apps off of the top of my head. There is [Issue #4664](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4664) in Google's Android code to add that feature to the base Gmail application. (I voted for it, but it hasn't been reviewed yet.)